# Refactoring repeated loop code with differing nested functions

Tags: java, for-loop, refactoring

I've got two for-loops going through a 2D pixel array for image manipulation purposes. I have various different methods I want to perform that will change what function is carried out on each pixel. However, the code for the for loops is repeated inside every one of these methods.

Is there some way I can pull it out?

```
/**
 * Get pixel array from current image.
 */
public void updatePixels() {
    pixels = new int[IMAGE_HEIGHT][IMAGE_WIDTH];
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col ++) {
            pixels[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Set pixel array to current image.
 */
public void commitPixels() {
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col ++) {
            image.setRGB(col, row, pixels[row][col]);
        }
    }
}

public void greyscale() {
    updatePixels();
    
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col++) {
            Color currentColour = new Color(pixels[row][col]);
            int r = currentColour.getRed();
            int g = currentColour.getGreen();
            int b = currentColour.getBlue();
            
            int avg = Math.round((float)((r + g + b) / 3));
            pixels[row][col] = new Color(avg, avg, avg).getRGB();
        }
    }
    commitPixels();
}

public void mirror() {
    updatePixels();
    
    int [][] pixelCopy = pixels.clone();
    
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col++) {
            pixels[row][col] = pixelCopy[row][IMAGE_WIDTH - col - 1];
        }
    }
    commitPixels();
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that moving `pixels[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);` and `image.setRGB(col, row, pixels[row][col]);`  respectively at the start and end of the inner loop in `greyscale` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the loop inside a method that takes a `BiConsumer` as parameter that gets the current column and row passed:

```java
private void forEachPixel(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
    for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length; col++) {
            consumer.accept(row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can write lambdas for what should be done inside the nested loop:

```java
public void updatePixels() {
    forEachPixel((row, col) -> pixels[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row));
}

public void commitPixels() {
    forEachPixel((row, col) -> image.setRGB(col, row, pixels[row][col]));
}

public void greyscale() {
    updatePixels();
    forEachPixel((row, col) -> {
        Color currentColour = new Color(pixels[row][col]);
        int r = currentColour.getRed();
        int g = currentColour.getGreen();
        int b = currentColour.getBlue();
        int avg = Math.round(((r + g + b) / 3f));
        pixels[row][col] = new Color(avg, avg, avg).getRGB();
    });
    commitPixels();
}

public void mirror() {
    updatePixels();
    int[][] pixelCopy = Arrays.stream(pixels).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new);
    forEachPixel((row, col) -> pixels[row][col] = pixelCopy[row][pixels[0].length - col - 1]);
    commitPixels();
}
```

*Remark:  In your question you are using `.clone()` on a 2d array inside `mirror()`. This creates a shallow-clone but you need a deep-clone for the logic that follows. This problem is fixed in my answer. In the `greyscale()` method, don't cast to float after the division but make the divisor a float (see my answer).*

Comment: Thanks, I don't believe I worded my question particularly clearly but this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems like the `updatePixels` and `commitPixel` could be moved inside the `for` loop of `greyscale`

```java
// updatePixel and commitPixel could be made inline as well.
public void updatePixel(int row, int col) {
    pixels[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
}
    

public void commitPixel(int row, int col) {
    image.setRGB(col, row, pixels[row][col]);    
}

public void computeColor(int row, int col) {
    Color currentColour = new Color(pixels[row][col]);
    int r = currentColour.getRed();
    int g = currentColour.getGreen();
    int b = currentColour.getBlue();
                
    int avg = Math.round((float)((r + g + b) / 3));
    pixels[row][col] = new Color(avg, avg, avg).getRGB();
}
    
public void greyscale() {
    pixels = new int[IMAGE_HEIGHT][IMAGE_WIDTH];
    
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col++) {
            updatePixel(row, col);
            computeColor(row, col);
            commitPixel(row, col);
        }
    }       
}
```

With this approach you can reduce the number of times the for loop is executed from 3 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loops are identical you can do all the actions on `pxels` in one method

```
public void greyscale() {
    pixels = new int[IMAGE_HEIGHT][IMAGE_WIDTH]; // updatePixels
    for (int row = 0; row < IMAGE_HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < IMAGE_WIDTH; col++) {
            pixels[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row); // updatePixels
            Color currentColour = new Color(pixels[row][col]);
            int r = currentColour.getRed();
            int g = currentColour.getGreen();
            int b = currentColour.getBlue();

            int avg = Math.round((float)((r + g + b) / 3));
            pixels[row][col] = new Color(avg, avg, avg).getRGB();
            image.setRGB(col, row, pixels[row][col]); // commitPixels
        }
    }
}
```